# Show push notification even app is in foreground(running) in Ionic Ios

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, push-notification, cordova-plugins

Is it possible to show push notification even app is running in ios using Ionic?

Comment: have you even checked the github docs:

https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugin-push/blob/master/docs/API.md

Answer (score 0):

ya you can,but you can show the dailog "New notification received" notify user instantly.

[image: Sample Image]